# Trying to add multiple D3 graphs

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, scope, d3.js

I'm trying to figure out how to include 2 or more graphs on my website. I am currently using the [Area Graph](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883195) and the [Pie Graph](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887235). If I disable one of them, then the other works fine, but when I try to use both at the same time, it stops working.

JS code for the Area Graph

```
var margin = { top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
width = 670 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 326 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
.range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
.range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("#watLenYearGra").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var area = d3.svg.area()
.x(function (d) { return x(d.date); })
.y0(height)
.y1(function (d) { return y(d.close); });

$("#watLenYear").click(function () {
    $("#watLenYearGra").slideToggle("fast");
});

d3.csv("data.csv", function (error, data) {
    data.forEach(function (d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.close; })]);

    svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Price ($)");

    svg.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("class", "area")
  .attr("d", area);
});
```

JS code for the Pie Graph

```
var width = 670,
    height = 326,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(0);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function (d) { return d.population; });

var svg = d3.select("#watLenSzGra").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

$("#watLenSz").click(function () {
    $("#watLenSzGra").slideToggle("fast");
});

d3.csv("data1.csv", function (error, data) {
    data.forEach(function (d) {
        d.population = +d.population;
    });

    var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(data))
     .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

    g.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.data.age); });

    g.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function (d) { return d.data.age; });
});
```

I think the problem lies with the scope of the variables (specifically the svg variable since they have the same name). Right now I have these sets of code in separate JS files, and I link them at the bottom of my body tag in the HTML file.

How can I limit these variables' scope to their files? Is that even the problem? Thanks

Comment: What errors do you get in Developer Tools / Firebug?

Comment: There are no errors that relate to the graphs

Comment: This article by Mike Bostock explains how to create charts in d3 that are reusable and that have the proper clousure, it may be helpful: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should work if you use [closures](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-closures):

```
(function() {
    var margin = { top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
    width = 670 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 326 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

    var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

    var svg = d3.select("#watLenYearGra").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function (d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function (d) { return y(d.close); });

    $("#watLenYear").click(function () {
        $("#watLenYearGra").slideToggle("fast");
    });

    d3.csv("data.csv", function (error, data) {
        data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
            d.close = +d.close;
        });

        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.date; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.close; })]);

        svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

        svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price ($)");

        svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("d", area);
    });
})();

(function() {
    var width = 670,
        height = 326,
        radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .outerRadius(radius - 10)
        .innerRadius(0);

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .sort(null)
        .value(function (d) { return d.population; });

    var svg = d3.select("#watLenSzGra").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    $("#watLenSz").click(function () {
        $("#watLenSzGra").slideToggle("fast");
    });

    d3.csv("data1.csv", function (error, data) {
        data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.population = +d.population;
        });

        var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
          .data(pie(data))
         .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "arc");

        g.append("path")
          .attr("d", arc)
          .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.data.age); });

        g.append("text")
          .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .style("text-anchor", "middle")
          .text(function (d) { return d.data.age; });
    });
})();
```